# ToggleGroup in a GXT ColumnConfig

Tags: gwt, cell, gxt

I'm using a `ColumnConfig` for presenting and editing data. For the gender I wann to have RadioButtons which where defined by an enumeration.

In every row i want to have:

**id  |  (x) male ( ) female  |   name   |   date**

The only way I have found was adding a "button" with defined rendering code. But there I cannot get the values or actions for pushed radio.

```
ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, String> begIdCol = createColumnConfig(begIdProvider, "Id", sizeBegId);

//gender
ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, GenderCode> genderCol = createColumnConfig(GRID_PROPERTIES.sex(), "Sex*", sizeGender);

ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, String> nameCol = createColumnConfig(GRID_PROPERTIES.name(), "Name*", sizeName);

ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, Date> birthdateCol = createColumnConfig(GRID_PROPERTIES.birthdate(), "Birthdate*", sizeBirthdate);
DateCell gebCell = new DateCell(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
geburtsdatumCol.setCell(gebCell);

//add fields to the row
List<ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, ?>> columnList = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, ?>>();
columnList.add(begIdCol);
columnList.add(genderCol);
columnList.add(nameCol);
columnList.add(birthdateCol);

ColumnModel<SomeValueGto> cm = new ColumnModel<SomeValueGto>(columnList);

ListStore<SomeValueGto> gridStore = new ListStore<SomeValueGto>(GRID_PROPERTIES.id());

myGrid = new SLGrid<SomeValueGto>(gridStore, cm);

// empty entries. default ids 1/2/3
myGrid.getStore().add(new SomeValueGto(1));
myGrid.getStore().add(new SomeValueGto(2));
myGrid.getStore().add(new SomeValueGto(3));

final GridInlineEditing<SomeValueGto> editing = new GridInlineEditing<SomeValueGto>(myGrid);
editing.setErrorSummary(false);
editing.addEditor(nameCol, new TextField());

final SLDateField dateField = new SLDateField("date", false, true);
editing.addEditor(geburtsdatumCol, new Converter<Date, Date>() {.....}, dateField);
```

The helper createColumnConfig:

```
private <T> ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, T> createColumnConfig(ValueProvider<SomeValueGto, T> aValueProvider, String aHeader, int aWidth) {
   ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, T> columnCol = new ColumnConfig<SomeValueGto, T>(aValueProvider);
   columnCol.setHeader(aHeader);
   columnCol.setWidth(aWidth);
   columnCol.setMenuDisabled(true);

   return columnCol;
}
```

Does anyone have already solved a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

GXT Grids uses `com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell` to render data in the grid. I don't think the kind of cell you want exist in GXT. So I think you will have to implement your own cell. You can take example of `ColorPaletteCell`, which allow the user to [select a color](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellgrid) from the cell itself.

So you will need to implement the `render` and `onBrowserEvent` methods to manage your radio buttons and what append when the user click on it.